# Is Laravel invisible-recaptcha safe?

Tags: laravel, recaptcha

In Laravel 7 / blade app using "albertcht/invisible-recaptcha": "^1.9"
I added rule
   'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'
to pages with common access as login, regsiter, contact_us
and added captcha in for definition of all these forms, like:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Login') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @captcha('en')
```

Can I consider all these pages safe from externall attacks?
Have I to take some additive steps? If yes, which ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All captchas will protect your forms only from spam attacks**.

There are also many other ways for attacking which you may consider other methods for protecting your forms.

But captcha (even **invisible-recaptcha**) will protect your forms from spammers.

Comment: Could you, please to point at ways for attacking and methods for protecting. Or link to good guide

Comment: Laravel itself is protected if you use it wisely, for example
1. you should guard the fields which should not be inserted by user
2. you should use validation which will protect forms from inserting unwanted values and data injection
3. you should use csrf for your forms
and ...

Comment: Also this link may help you https://medium.com/@advanceidea/laravel-security-65bafe44b0a